# Connect to the server which its ip is dynamically assigned

Tags: dynamic-ip

I'd like to develop the app which run on a mobile phone. It acts like a server which is able to be accessed from the PC app which will request for the mobile info such as the GPS coordination. The mobile phone running this app will be response automatically with out human action.

The point is the mobile phone could be in the GSM/CDMA or Wifi network which its ip address is dynamically assigned.

Do you guys has any idea how to connect to the server on the public network with dynamically ip assignment like this?

P.S. The mobile phone can connect to the PC app, since I can set up a dns service stuff on the PC side. Just let you guys know.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to pull from a device on a mobile network is going to a pain. It's very likely to be on a NATed ip which means no direct access, and there's no easy way around that.

You'd be a lot better off changing the software on the mobile device to some form of a daemon that *PUSHS* the data to a centralised server rather than attempting to get the server to pull from the phone.

Of course, there's other hacks you could use like implementing something like SSH tunnels. In this case, the mobile device would create an SSH connection to a centralised server which then allows connection back to the mobile device on a certain port. However, managing this with multiple devices would become a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be registering a host name for the mobile phone on a service like [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) and letting the mobile phone update the dynamic IP whenever it changes.

If it's GSM you may be able to acces it, but if it's on a WiFi surely not without any port redirection ... difficult.